# How to convert a completablefuture to Rxjava?

Tags: java, java-8, rx-java

I am using a completablefuture to chain a bunch of async operation, I am wondering how to covert it to use RxJava, especially what's the benefit of using Rxjava vs CompletableFuture?

```
CompletableFuture cf = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> System.out.println("hello");
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this because it looks to me as an exact duplicate... if not please re-pharse your question

Comment: RxJava 2 Jdk 8 Interop has a converter for it: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Jdk8Interop#completionstage-to-rxjava

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between completableFuture,Future and Observable Rxjava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329845/difference-between-completablefuture-future-and-observable-rxjava)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Completable` from a `Future` by calling the factory method [`Completable.fromFuture(cf)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#fromFuture(java.util.concurrent.Future)).

More informations about futures and RxJava are given with [Difference between completableFuture,Future and Observable Rxjava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329845/difference-between-completablefuture-future-and-observable-rxjava) as mentioned by a commenter.

> RxJava is whole library for reactive programming. At a glance, it will appear to be similar to Java 8's streams, which it is, except it's much more powerful.

Answer (score 0):

RxJava targets **JRE 1.6**, which is why the `CompletableFuture` is not supported out of the box. There are a few libraries out there that bridge the gap, like **future-converter**:

- https://github.com/lukas-krecan/future-converter - the library
- https://github.com/lukas-krecan/future-converter/blob/master/rxjava-java8/src/main/java/net/javacrumbs/futureconverter/java8rx/FutureConverter.java  - the entry point for conversion
- https://github.com/lukas-krecan/future-converter/blob/master/rxjava2-common/src/main/java/net/javacrumbs/futureconverter/rxjava2common/RxJava2FutureUtils.java - implementation

The answer given by @tynn is not recommended though - calling `.fromFuture(cf)` would create a non-asynchronous model, because it relies on calling the blocking `Future.get()`. Unlike the basic `Future`, `CompletableFuture` if fully asynchronous as it provides a callback mechanism. 
`